# Setup wxWidget in Netbeans 6.1 C++ On MS Windows?

Tags: c++, configuration, netbeans, wxwidgets

Im running Netbeans 6.1 with C++ Plugin and cygwin (gcc compiler) how do I setup wxWidget to work with it?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.daltonfilho.com/2008/02/23/wxwidgets-on-windows-using-netbeans-60-with-mingw-msys/ seams to work.