# Setting up Netbeans to compile wxWidgets projects under Windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, wxwidgets

I'm trying to set up my Netbeans IDE so that it is capable of compiling wxWidgets projects.

There is very similar question: 
[Setup wxWidget in Netbeans 6.1 C++ On MS Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152140/setup-wxwidget-in-netbeans-6-1-c-on-ms-windows)
but the answer is not working for me. And the mentioned versions are a bit outdated.

I use the mingw package for compilation. 
There is no problem compiling a small hello World App from the console using this command in mysys:

```
$ g++ hello.cpp `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` -o hello.exe
```

So here's what I tried in Netbeans:
**Project properties:**

- C++ Compiler -> Additional Options: `wx-config cxxflags` *(surrounded by backticks)*
- C++ Compiler -> Include directories: installation_Path/include
- Linker -> Additional Options: `wx-config --libs` *(surrounded by backticks)*

The command lines Netbeans creates when I try to compile seem to be correct to me

```
g++.exe `wx-config --cxxflags` -c -g -I/D/lib/wxWidgets/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

This compiles without errors

```
g++.exe `wx-config --cxxflags`  `wx-config --libs` -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/wxwidgetstest build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/lib/wxWidgets/lib/gcc_lib
```

But during the linking process I get loads of errors...

**Questions:**

- Does anybody have a working configuration for compiling wxWidgets Projects from within Netbeans and can help me out
- Or does anybody see an error in the command lines could be the reason for the linking problems ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried running `wx-config --cxxflags` & `wx-config --libs` in a shell and putting the output in their respective fields in Project properties? Perhaps whatever method NetBeans uses for running g++ does not handle command substitution properly or not at all.

Comment: I have tried it sometime in my try&error process but it didn't work. Thank you for answer anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution, and wrote a guide for anyone who might encounter the same problem in the future.

[wxWidgets wiki: Compiling using Netbeans](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_using_Netbeans)